# iPhone - Can't kill my thread with loop

Tags: iphone, multithreading

I see "killThread" in my log, but the thread doesn't stop. If I set mKillThread to true before calling the loop it will never run. I tried simply bool mKillThread and using a property and self.mKillThread... Below are the only references to mKillThread in the code.

Init:

```
mKillThread = false;
//mKillThread = true;
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(threadLoop) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

Thread stuff:

```
// Called on main thread
- (void)killThread {   
    NSLog(@"killThread");
    mKillThread = true;
}

- (void)threadLoop {
    while ( !mKillThread ) {
        if ( mKillThread ) {

            NSLog(@"killthread haha!");
            return;
        }
        NSLog(@"looping!");
    }
}
```

EDIT -

Figured it out, I had 2 views in the xib set to MyViewSubclass so I was creating 2 threads. I was only calling killThread on the custom view I had hooked up and not the other. OMG.

Comment: Corrected syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting your variable mKillThread to volatile. That will say to the compiler that this variable will be used in more than one thread, and it shouldn't do some optimization which could cause your problem.

```
volatile bool mKillThread;
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the compiler optimized away the `if` clause altogether, because it can infer that inside the `while` loop `mKillThread` must be `false`, therefore `if` clause is not necessary.

Note that (Objective-)C(++) compiler is allowed to do this kind of optimizations.

To tell the compiler that a variable can be accessed from another thread and so on, use `volatile`. 
Or accessing it via the getter also  suffices, `[self mKillThread]`.